# Select all children with a parent ID as a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I have data like this :

```
id     parent_id       name
-----------------------------
 1        0            John
 10       1            Anna
 11       1            Doe
 2        0            Brian
 101      10           Chris
```

Now, i want to select all record (and itself) with parent id as parameter. for example, if parameter = 0 then would return all record.

This is desired result for `WHERE PARENT_ID = 1`

```
id     parent_id       name
-----------------------------
 1        0            John
 10       1            Anna
 11       1            Doe
 101      10           Chris
```

Record with id = 101 includes in resultset because parent = 10 which id 10 is child of id = 1.
I have no clue to solved this.

I try :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE PARENT_ID = 1
OR ID = 1
```

This not return record with parent_id = 10. Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+recursive-query

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you give me a specific link or answer for this question? I am really have no clue what to do.

Comment: @JamieD77 Can you please explain how to use `CONNECT BY PRIOR` in where clause?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want build [Hierarchical Query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE 1=1
START WITH ID = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = PARENT_ID
```

edit:
result:

```
 ID  PARENT_ID  NAME
  1          0  John
 10          1  Anna
101         10  Chris
 11          1  Doe
```

Comment: This did not give me desired result. It's always retrieve all records.

Comment: Still retrieve all records. for information, column id and parent_id is varchar2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE START WITH ID = 1 CONNECT BY PARENT_ID = PRIOR ID
```